# WebView se cierra Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Tengo una app la cual al usarla automáticamente te carga en *webview* la web, el problema es que tengo el método para que atrás vaya regresando lo navegado en la web pero al no quedar mas se cierra la app automáticamente.

¿De qué forma puedo hacer que cuando ya no se pueda regresar mas en la web, mande un cuadro de dialogo que muestre si quieres o no cerrar la app? (no uso *fragment*).

Este es el código:

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private WebView mWebView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.mWebView);
        WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);


        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        // Url que carga la app (webview)
        mWebView.loadUrl("https://www.google.com/?hl=es");

        // Forzamos el webview para que abra los enlaces internos dentro de la la APP
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());


    }
    //esto es para que funcione el volver atras en WebView
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        boolean response;
        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)) {
            if(mWebView.canGoBack()){
                mWebView.goBack();
                response = true;
            }else{
                response = super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
            }
        }else{
            response = super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
        }
        return response;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pues, yo lo haría de la siguiente forma:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        switch (keyCode) {
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
                if (mWebView.canGoBack()) {
                    mWebView.goBack();
                } else {
                    cerrarApp();
                }
                return true;
        }

    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}

//lo siguiente es crear un método que nos muestre un cuadro de diálogo cuando ya no haya más que mostrar en el webview
private void cerrarApp(){
    new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        .setTitle("¡Atención!")
        .setMessage("Estas apunto de cerrar la app, ¿Desea continuar?")
        .setPositiveButton("Sí", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            finish();    
        }

    })
    .setNegativeButton("Cancelar", null)
    .show();
}
```

Me dices si te ha funcionado

Comment: funciono perfecto muchas gracias